# Using an ASP.Net class object (asp.net project is WCF service) from ajax (jquery)

Tags: asp.net, ajax, json, wcf

I have a WCF service which sends string lists from client(jquery web pages).The wcf project runs perfect in visual studio when I run it with F5,a window is opening and I'm clicking Invoke after I can see the list object under the Invoke.I will using my list datas in jquery so I'm using ajax to call my wcf service,all configuration settings are right. I'm using `abc` class which have a list veriable,and I have a function data which sets some data to that list. Here is my Service contract and Data contract form WCF(IService1.cs):

```
namespace kgms
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IService1
    {
        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
        abc data(abc obj);
   }
   [DataContract]
        public class abc {
            [DataMember]
            public List<string> sval { get; set; }
            [DataMember]
            public List<string> kval { get; set; }
        }
}
```

And here is my data function info(Service1.svc.cs):

```
namespace kgms
{
   [AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
    public class Service1 : IService1
    {
       public abc data(abc obj) {
               obj.sval.Add("asd");
               obj.sval.Add("sdf");
               obj.kval.Add("example");
               obj.kval.Add(":-)");
            return obj;
        }
    }
}
```

I will access from that ajax call:

```
$('#buton').click(function () {
Type = "POST";
            Url = "http://compname/sil/Service1.svc/data";
            ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
            DataType = "json"; var ProcessData = true;
            CallService();

        });
 function CallService() {
            $.ajax({
                type: Type,
                url: Url,
                data: Object,
                contentType: ContentType,
                dataType: DataType,
                processdata: ProcessData,
                success: function (msg) {
                    ServiceSucceeded(msg);
                },
                error: ServiceFailed
            });
        }
        function ServiceFailed(result) {
            alert("basarisiz");
            alert('Service call failed: ' + result.status + '' + result.statusText);
            Type = null; varUrl = null; Data = null; ContentType = null; DataType = null; ProcessData = null;
        }
        function ServiceSucceeded(result) {
            alert("good");
        }
    });
```

what parameter must I send with `Data: Object` Object is sample, what must write instead of Object. Because my WCF function is taking an abc class object, what can I do.

Answer (score 1):

hope this help you.

```
 var abcCtor = function() {
     this.sval  = [];
     this.kval  = [];
 }

 var mainObj = function() {
    this.abc = new abcCtor();
 }

 var abcObj = new mainObj();
    abcObj.abc.sval.push('name');
    abcObj.abc.sval.push('age');

    abcObj.abc.kval.push('jhonatas');
    abcObj.abc.kval.push('00');

var jsonValue = JSON.stringify(abcObj);
```

Then, pass the jsonValue to the paramater Data, of $ajax.

**EDIT:**

Simple do:

```
  public abc data() {
               obj.sval.Add("asd");
               obj.sval.Add("sdf");
               obj.kval.Add("example");
               obj.kval.Add(":-)");
            return obj;
        }
```

And omit the Data parameter from $ajax

Comment: I don't will add some datas from jquery, I will only call successfully the data function

Comment: Then, why you are expecting parameters in your c# method?

I will edit my answer. Look that you dont need expect any parameter in your method if you wont use them.

Comment: Because my data function is running only when a parameter is comming.

Comment: Ok. So you need to do one of the two things. Change your parameters in c# class, or send parameters in json format, in $ajax method.

Comment: but giving obj doesn't exist,I have tried this ways ,and I creted obj object in data method, but nothing,when I take obj from parameter of data it's running,but when I create obj on any where unlike parameter it isn't running